# How to copy CustomElementRegistry to a child window?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-component, custom-element

Once we've called `window.open(...)`, how do we get the same Custom Element tags to also work in the new window?

Comment: Parent can trigger code in the child and the child can sent message to the parent window: Maybe this gives some insight: http://usefulangle.com/post/4/javascript-communication-parent-child-window

Answer (score 1):

The new window is a new context meaning that it knows nothing of the opener directly.

It has a new `window` object so no globals from the old window are available.

You would need to load all of your JS files into this new window's html to be able to access Web Components.

You can communicate between the two windows but even that is fairly limited. http://usefulangle.com/post/4/javascript-communication-parent-child-window

Comment: Yes, you need to recreate Custom Elements, But the child knows its opener: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener

Comment: Seems like some pain here. F.e., maybe I don't own all the Custom Element classes, and I am using 3rd party Custom Elements. So I need to load all the libraries over in the child window first then, but that seems very inefficient. And then, if there are singletons in those libraries, it may lead to oddities with multiple instances across windows. With React portals, I can easily render DOM elements into another window while all the React logic entirely lives in the parent Window. I'd like to do something similar with Custom Elements.

Comment: You can always send message between the original window and opened window. So you can pass limited data between them. Loading the components in both pages is not a big issue. You just include the scripts twice.

Comment: @Intervalia And then we need to include the styles twice too. And then we need to wire up event handling to go across windows, etc... It's not just "easy". See this idea I came up with to make it easy: https://discourse.wicg.io/t/idea-same-document-same-context-windows-declaratively-via-html/3556